# imagemagick convert -crop with pipe before it

Tags: image-processing, pipe, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to use imagemagick to crop an image.
However, imagemagick will be receiving the image data to crop through a pipe before it:

```
exiftool -b -RawThermalImage image1.jpg | convert .....-crop.....
```

I am not sure what to put in the ".....-crop.....", to crop the image data received to a specific area. Please guide.

Usually, after convert, an image is specified for cropping like:

```
convert rose: -crop 1x1+3+3 cropped.gif
```

But, in this case, I am confused as to how to complete this command given that the image is coming in from the pipe.

ImageLink:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14h3z0yFK_9_f2puzbhLUm3D50MDMMnu2/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

It transpires that the problem was caused by inadvertently using **GraphicsMagick** rather than **ImageMagick**.

**Original Answer**

You should be able to use a dash `-` to refer to the `stdin` if that stream has a well-known magic number (signature) at the start:

```
exiftool -b -RawThermalImage image1.jpg | convert - -crop ... result.jpg
```

---

If the stream is raw, or doesn't have a known magic number/signature, you will need to give **ImageMagick** a hint, so if it is raw greyscale 8-bit data with shape 640x480, use:

```
exiftool -b -RawThermalImage image1.jpg | convert -size 640x480 -depth 8 GRAY:- -crop ... result.jpg
```

---

If it's RGB888 data with size 80x80, use:

```
exiftool -b -RawThermalImage image1.jpg | convert -depth 8 -size 80x80 RGB:- -crop ... result.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Using the first format, gives me the error 'convert convert: Unable to open file () [No such file or directory].'
I have added the image I am using to my post.

Comment: Even when I break the command into 2 separate commands by putting the output of the first half of the command into a .png image, and then using that png image into the second half of the command in place of the '-', I get the same error.

Comment: @bigtree Can you share your image via Google Drive or Dropbox or similar - I think Stack Overflow's `imgur` strips the raw thermal image out. If I do this I get an empty file `exiftool -b -RawThermalImage 42gyq.jpg > a`

Comment: I have added the Google Drive link now. Thanks.

Comment: For reference, the original command is:
`exiftool -b -RawThermalImage imagename.jpg 2>/dev/zero | convert - -crop 1x1+0+0 -colorspace gray -format "%[mean]" info:`

Comment: @bigtree Ok, if I extract the file using `exiftool -b -RawThermalImage imagename.jpg > a` I get a valid TIFF in `a` with dimensions 160x120 which I can check with `exiftool a` Do you get that at least?

Comment: Yes, I get that as well.

Comment: So can you now do `convert a result.jpg` ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to do `convert a result.jpg`

Comment: How about `exiftool -b -RawThermalImage image1.jpg | convert TIFF:- extracted.jpg`

Comment: I am able to run this command and then do `exiftool extracted.jpg`. It shows that it is a 160x120, 527 byte image.

Comment: So you should be able to run the command I presume you want `exiftool -b -RawThermalImage imagename.jpg 2>/dev/zero | convert TIFF:- -crop 1x1+0+0 -colorspace gray -format "%[mean]" info:`

Comment: This command gives me the same error:
`convert convert: Unable to open file () [No such file or directory].`

Comment: Weird! Try `exiftool ... | convert TIF:fd:0 -crop ...`

Comment: getting this: error `convert convert: Unable to open file (fd:0) [No such file or directory].`

Comment: Mmm... can you share a screngrab of the command you typed and the error message please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243140/discussion-between-mark-setchell-and-big-tree).